# why $\left(\left( \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{-2}\right)^\frac{1}{4}\right) \neq \left(\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)$?

Tags: contest-math, exponentiation

Why $\left(\left( \left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{-2}\right)^\frac{1}{4}\right) \neq \left(\left(-\frac{1}{4}\right)^{-\frac{1}{2}}\right)$?

well, I tried this question but as far my calculations, I am getting $(((\frac {-1}{4})^{-2})^\frac {1}{4})= 2$  where as $((\frac {-1}{4})^{-1/2})= \frac {2} {i}$ .

But since $((a)^b)^c=a^{bc}$,  shouldn't these two give the same answer ?

Please help me.

Thanks in advance .

Comment: $(a^b)^c=a^{bc}$ is not *always* true. See [exponentiation and Logarithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch#Exponentiation_to_fractional_powers).

Comment: Much simpler would be to ask why $((-1)^2)^{1/4}\ne (-1)^{1/2}$. It's the same problem.

Comment: Remember order of operations, resolving the parentheses and then exponents, which shows in this case $(a^b)^c \neq a^{bc}$

Comment: Exponentiation for negative bases is not well defined.

Comment: oh..I see . Thanks everyone! actually our text book said that $(a^b)^c = a^{bc}$ so I was wondering if it was true for negative numbers but seems like it is not !

Comment: It is not _necessarily_ true.

Comment: Hey! you barely had 100 rep a few days ago, now at 500+ I am hugely impressed.You have a great future ahead, and you'll not just clear INMO but will represent India in IMO.

Comment: @Arjun Thank you so much . This means a lot. Hope what you are saying becomes true one day.

Comment: Just to be clear: $(a^b)^c$ _is_ equal to $a^{bc}$ for all $b,c\in\Bbb R$, as long as $a> 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By squaring -1/4 you lose the (-1).

The real problem can be made obvious by observing the problem is roughly equal to $ ((-1)^2)^{(1/4)}=(-1)^{(1/2)}$, the specific numbers and  inverse don’t matter. Thus you will see you have $ (1)^{1/4}=(-1)^{1/2}$, something essentially  like $(1)^{1/2}=(-1)^{1/2}$, which is now obviously false.

The issue is that the powers is not always commutable, $(a^b)^c \neq (a^c)^b$.

Another fundamental issue is that on the left side you are doing calculations in real field, on the right side you are doing calculations on the complex field.  If you do both in real field and define root as solution to polynomial equation, you will see the problem more clearly, on the left side you get 2 and -2. On the right side you get nothing. If you do both in complex field, you get on the left side 2 and -2, 2i and -2i, on the right side you get 2i and -2i.

So the problem is really about how you define root and in what field you are doing your calculations. In order to understand it you probably need to learn a bit abstract algebra and complex analysis.

Answer (score 3):

Note that $\sqrt[n]{x^n}=|x|$ with $n$ even:
$$(((-4)^2)^{1/2})^{1/2}=(|-4|)^{1/2}=2$$